# Cannot connect to WindowsServer from Centos7 due to ProxyError

Tags: windows, ansible

I am trying to connect to Windows Server 2012 from my ansible server (Centos7).

Let's assume its host is x and port is y 
I managed to connect to other linux based servers but I cannot connect to the windows one.

I followed [the tutorial here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_windows.html) and after all setups and configurations I get the following error:

```
root@localhost: ansible# ansible windows -i hosts -m win_ping --ask-vault-pass
Vault password:
WindowsServer | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x', port=y): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))",
```

This is my group_vars/windows.yml file:

```
# it is suggested that these be encrypted with ansible-vault:
# ansible-vault edit group_vars/windows.yml

ansible_user: Administrator
ansible_password: password
ansible_port: y
ansible_connection: winrm
```

This is my hosts file snippet:

```
[windows]
WindowsServer ansible_host=x
```

I did configure windows server [with this file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1).

Please help, I have no idea what to do to make the connection work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As J and Mike from ansible google group suggested:**
The reason of the error were environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY that ansible used from the system.

To let ansible know that you are using proxy you have to:
*1. Locate transport.py that comes with pywinrm

2. modify the following line session.trust_env to make it false.*

```
125         # configure proxies from HTTP/HTTPS_PROXY envvars
126 #        session.trust_env = True
127         session.trust_env = False
```

*3.  pywinrm will no longer check your local env for a proxy.*

After that I also neeeded to add one more variable to group_vars/windows.yml file:

```
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```